# Regarding expansion of bilinear form relative to basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector spaces with basis $\{x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$ and  $\{y_1, y_2,\cdots, y_n\}$ respectively and $\mathbb{K}$ be the real and complex field. Let $B:X\times Y\longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$ be a bilinear map. Then is it true that there exists linear maps $\phi_j:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$ and $\psi_j:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$ for $1\leq j\leq n$, such that 
$$B(x,y)=\sum_{1}^{n}\phi_j(x)\psi_j(y)$$ for every $(x,y)\in X\times Y$?

Comment: Yes, you can always do this. The minimum number of summands possible is called the *rank* of the bilinear form, and it’s known that the rank is at most $n$. After picking a basis for either $X$ or $Y$, it’s not very difficult to write down the functionals $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$: one of them will be dual to the basis you picked.

Comment: @Joppy Can you tell how $\phi_j$ and $\psi_j$ will be defined?

Comment: Suppose that $\phi_j$ is dual to the basis $x_i$. How could you use this, along with $B$, to produce some other maps $\psi_j$?

Comment: @Joppy okay.. suppose $f_j$ is the dual basis for $x_j$'s and $g_j$ is the dual basis for $y_j$'s then for example will $ \phi_1(x)=f_1(x)$ and $\psi_1(x)=g_1(x)B(x_1,y_1)$....? Am I correct?

Comment: I think this is almost correct, but when you sum everything up, you only get $B(x_i, y_i)$ appearing. The solution should include the cross terms $B(x_i, y_j)$.